# How Do I bind javascript type of File to a Nancy Model containing HttpFile?

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, nancy

I'm trying to bind a put request that contains File in typescript to Nancy's HttpFile. The request always sets the HttpFile in C# to null. Is there a way to do this?

```
@Injectable()
export class FileUploadService {

  @Output() progress: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

  /**
   * uploads a file to the service and returns the document's id
   */

  public upload(req: IUploadRequest): Observable<number> {

let promise = new Promise((resolve: any, reject: any) => {

  let xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.upload.onprogress = (event: any) => {
    let progress = Math.round(event.lengthComputable ? event.loaded * 100 / event.total : 0);
    this.progress.emit(progress);
  };

  xhr.onload = () => {
    let json = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
    resolve(<number>json.documentId);
  };

  xhr.onerror = () => {
    reject(xhr.response);
  };

  xhr.onabort = () => {
    reject(xhr.response);
  };

  xhr.open("PUT", `${environment.API_ROOT}/document`, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader(environment.AUTH_HEADER_NAME, getToken());
  let formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", <File>req.file, req.file.name);

  formData.append("description", req.description);
  formData.append("chapterId", req.chapterId.toString());
  xhr.send(formData);
});

return Observable.fromPromise(promise);
  }
}

export class IUploadRequest {
  public file: File;
  public description: string;
  public chapterId: number;
}
```

The model I'm trying to bind to...

```
    public class FileUploadRequest
{
    public long ContentSize { get; set; }
    public HttpFile File { get; set; }
    public string  Description { get; set; }
    public int ChapterId { get; set; }
}
```

And in the C# API...

```
 var request = this.Bind<FileUploadRequest>();
```

What am I doing wrong? "file" always comes back as null in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an FYI... I fixed this by going into the request itself and grabbing the File in Request.File.